# How can a logged in user comment on a post? django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I wrote the codes for commenting system and whenever you want to add a comment to a post, You'll be redirected to a page that you can write your comment and choose which member you are.

How can I fix the member field with the user that is currently logged in to the site?

And how can I make the comment section only down the post and not being redirected to another page?

Here's my view.py

```
def comment_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('samplepost', slug=post.slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blogapp/comment.html', {'form': form})
```

and here is my models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='comments')
    body = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: show your forms.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How can I fix the member field with the user that is currently logged in to the site?" - to access the current logged in user, use `request.user` in your Django template. This gives you the User object. If you have a username field in the User model, you can of course use `request.user.username` to get the username.

"And how can I make the comment section only down the post and not being redirected to another page?" - I'm assuming you mean placing the comment section below the post and posting comments without redirecting the page. For that, create the comment section as a textarea inside a form, place the element wherever you want using HTML and CSS, and use an AJAX request to post the form input to the backend.